# sum multiple digits if cell contains some symbols

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum

I have a datagridview where I'm counting the value from a column and multiply for another column value, then do the sum for all the rows and display the result in label with this code:

```
int sum2 = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++m)
            {
                sum2 += getCellRepsSum(dataGridView1.Rows[m]);
            }
     
        label18.Text = sum2.ToString();


       

        int getCellRepsSum(DataGridViewRow dr)
        {
            int serie = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[1].Value);


            int l = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[2].Value); //reps


            int result = 0;



            result = serie * l;
            return result;
        }
```

This works fine if I set a number, but what I want to add a condition based on the presence of symbols like + or -.

So something like... if cell value of "ripetizioni" column contains "-" or "+" then sum the numbers between each symbols and then multiply like my code do.

Example: 12-8-6 need to sum 12 + 8 + 6 then multiply for "serie" column like in my code etc.

I've tried like this but don't work because the "-" symbol doesn't permit the ToInt Conversion:

```
int sum2 = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++m)
            {
                sum2 += getCellRepsSum(dataGridView1.Rows[m]);
            }
     
        label18.Text = sum2.ToString();


       

        int getCellRepsSum(DataGridViewRow dr)
        {
            int serie = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[1].Value);

            int result = 0;
            string l = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells[2].Value);

            if (l.Contains("-")) {

                int lt = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[2].Value);
                int sumReps = 0;

                

                while (lt > 0)
                {
                    sumReps += (lt % 10);

                    lt = lt / 10;
                }
                result = sumReps;
                return result;

            }
            else {
                //reps

                int li = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[2].Value); //reps




                result = serie * li;
                return result;
            }
            
            return result;
        }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int lt = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[2].Value);
```

To

```
int lt = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split('+','-').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

Don't forget to multiply it by `serie`

Comment: yes, I modified like this and works: if (l.Contains("-")) {

                    int lt = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split('+', '-').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
                  

                    

                    
                    result = lt * serie;
                    return result;

                } Do you know how I can add the "or +" in Contains function?

Comment: To be honest, you can just remove the `if(Contains` - `dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split('+', '-').Select(int.Parse).Sum();` will result in `2` for an input of `"2"` and result in `4` for an input of `"1+3"`

Comment: removing the if condition throw an error when the serie column is filled before the ripetizioni column. I fix like this and works fine: if (l.Contains("-") || l.Contains("+")) {

                    int lt = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split('+', '-').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
                    result = lt ;
                    return result;

                }
                else {
                    int li = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[2].Value); //reps
                    result = serie * li;
                    return result;
                }